# upgrade from xenserver 6.0.2 to new version

Tags: xenserver, citrix, upgrade

I have a pool with 2 hosts and 12 VMs. The VMs are on an attached SR. 
Currently, the version of XenServer is 6.0.2 and I need to upgrade to 7.1 but I was wondering what's the best way to do that considering I'm not an expert. 
I have 2 choices:

- Use Rolling pool upgrade
- Install as new the version 7.1

For both, I need some advice, so if I use

**Rolling pool upgrade** is this method stable enough to do this operation from 6.0.2 to 7.1? anyone had experience with that?

**Install as new the version 7.1**, in this case, I would proceed in this way:

1. shut down all VMs
2. backup all VMs information with `xe pool-dump-database file-name=backupPool`
3. detach server number one from the original pool
4. detach the SR from the original pool
5. install from scratch XenServer 7.1 on server number one
6. create a new pool with only server number one on it
7. attach the SR to the new pool
8. import the backup taken at point 2
9. now if everything is ok, I should be able to start the VMs and start again from point 5 with the server number 2

what's the best and safest way to proceed?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I tested it few months ago, it was upgrade from 6.2 to 7.1 by **rolling pool upgrade** and I did not had any issues.

I did it in steps:  6.2 > 6.5 > 7.0 > 7.1

About my upgrade - it was cluster with three nodes.
I did upgrade by webserver with all necessary files that was set up on my workstation. 
Steps you mentioned are OK.

Prepare first and dont forget about all necessary patches that was released by Citrix along the way.

1. read necessary documents on upgrade,
2. backup settings
3. proceed

**Godspeed**

Comment: after a lot of reading in forum and after test on single server, the way i performed the upgrade from XenServer 6.0.2 to XenServer 7.6 was simply by using the iso of the 7.6
The process is simple, just shutdown all vm's and the server, boot the server from the ISO of 7.6 and during the installation it is possibile to do an upgrade of current installation. The upgrade is a clean procedures, the only issue i had, was on reconnecting the SR: the iqn was different but i recovered it from the xe pool-dump-database file-name=backupPool done before the upgrade